# What is the best way to know which protocols are supported by curl in python?

Tags: pycurl

I am building a python application that is used to download remote files. In most cases, we use `pycurl` to do the actual download but we need to define a class that wraps the `pycurl` object. The class can handle several protocols (`HTTP(S)`, `FTP(S)` and `SFTP`).

We have noticed that on some distributions (for example Ubuntu 18.04), `cURL` doesn't support the `SFTP` protocol. So using some `SFTP`-related options (`SSH_KNOWNHOSTS` for instance) leads to crashes (the crash occurs when setting the option **before the download** even if the URL uses another protocol). Therefore we need to know which protocols are available when the class is defined (i.e. when importing the module).

What is the best way to know, in python, which protocols are supported by `cURL` ? I know that the output of `pycurl.version_info()` contains the supported protocols (item 8) but is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

pycurl does not track or check which protocols are supported by libcurl.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. `version_info()` provides a way to know which protocols are available.

Comment: It does, and that information comes directly out of libcurl.

Comment: We agree on that. Maybe you can edit or delete your answer.

Comment: Feel free to rephrase your question.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. If you think that there is something unclear in my question, don't hesitate to comment and I will be happy to clarify it.

Comment: pycurl does not support, or not support, protocols. It forwards the commands to libcurl and forwards results back to your application.

Comment: I know. I was talking about a way to know in python the protocols supported by cURL. The title is a bit ambiguous and a sentence was.

Comment: Okay. If you are asking what APIs libcurl provides to determine protocol support you should ask that, and tag the question appropriately. "Best" is opinion based regardless.